# Case-by-case $.ajaxSetup calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching

I'm making a couple `$.post` calls in my script, and I'd like to use `$.ajaxSetup` to handle cache control.

```
function function1() 
$.ajaxSetup({
    type: 'POST',
    headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache", "pragma-cache": "no-cache" }
});
$.post('getLists.php', {user: authUser, token: authToken}, function(data){
    $('nav a[class!=btnNewList]').remove();
    $.each(data.objects, function(index, element){
        $('nav').append('<a href="#" data-list-id="'+element.id+'">'+element.title+'</a>');
    });
    $('nav').children('a:first-child').next('a').addClass('selected');

    getClipsForList($('nav').children('a:first-child').next('a').attr('data-list-id'));
}, 'json');


function function2(){
$.ajaxSetup({
    type: 'POST',
    headers: { "cache-control": "public", "pragma-cache": "public" }
});
$.post('getClips.php', {user: authUser, token: authToken}, function(data){
    spinner.stop();
    $.each(data.objects, function(index, element){
        if(element.list == '/api/lists/'+id+'/'){
            $('#clips ul').append('<li data-url="'+element.url+'">'+truncate(element.title, 100)+'</li>');
        }
    });
},'json');
}
```

I'm building a mobile web app, and I noticed it was caching my JSON responses, so I did some research and found the `$.ajaxSetup` solution. It worked great, but it seems now, regardless of what I set the cache control property to, it's *always* caching now. I'd like to cache only certain $.post calls. Any way to do this?

I've tried using `$.ajax` instead of `$.post` for the function I want cached data and setting the global property to false, but it still won't cache.

Comment: Why don't you just use `$.ajax` where you can specify those settings directly?

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I wanted to avoid using $.ajax in favour of $.post as it's a little cleaner but it seems to be the best way, and is now working. Thanks!

Comment: I would argue that using $.ajax is cleaner than using $.ajaxSetup more than once.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by simply using $.ajax for each call and explicity settings the headers on a per call basis, rather than trying to use a global setup with $.post.